# Delphi Elevate Privileges Button

Tags: delphi, uac, delphi-xe3

I am pretty new to Delphi XE and I see that the button component has a elevate privileges option.

However if set to true UAC doesn't prompt on click. How can I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton.ElevationRequired) explains that setting the `ElevationRequired` property to `True` adds the shield icon. It doesn't indicate that clicking the button automatically invokes a UAC (elevation) prompt.

> Puts a shield icon on a button, indicating that elevated access rights are required.

The code you provide for the button's `OnClick` event should start a process that requires elevation (which will then prompt for credentials). You can use `ShelllExecuteEx` with the `runas` verb for doing so.